# GridLayout in Android

Tags: android

I just created a new android application, so I only have the MainActivity.java file and its corresponding xml layout file (activity_main.xml). The contents of the activity_main.xml file is:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:columnCount="2"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:rowCount="2" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/blueButton"
    android:background="#236B8E" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/redButton"
    android:background="#FF0000" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/yellowButton"
    android:background="#FFFF00" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/greenButton"
    android:background="#00FF00" />

</GridLayout>
```

When I run the application, all I see is a white screen with the "Main Activity" bar at the top. Is there anything wrong with my xml file?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Button android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Translate"
    android:background="#00FF00"
    />
```

Add all these properties to your buttons.and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have red,blue,green and yellow button inside the gridview as each items, then you have to write a separate xml file for that. using that xml file in an Adapter you can populate those buttons as each item in the gridView.

More on how to do this is nicely expalined in [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

First of all put some code from java file .
Do you have setContentview ?
This XML code is fine ,it works correctly..

try out this

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gridView1"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:gravity="center"
android:columnWidth="50dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</GridView>
```

JAVA CODE:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class GridViewActivity extends Activity {

GridView gridView;

static final String[] numbers = new String[] { 
        "A", "B", "C", "D", "E",
        "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
        "K", "L", "M", "N", "O",
        "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T",
        "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numbers);

    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
            int position, long id) {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            ((TextView) v).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your code here, I tried it with creating new application project and it works just fine.have you set API level properly, minimum API level 14 to be set to use GridLayout. And have you set setContentView for this layoutin your java code

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:columnWidth="50dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</GridView>
```